# Authorize ShinyApps In Rstudio

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to authorize my shinyapps account on my Rstudio console, but when I run the setAccountInfo() , i get the following error

```
 Failed to connect to api.shinyapps.io port 443: Connection refused
```

I am under a proxy connection in my college.although i have run the following code to work under proxy and it used to work for installing packages from github etc. but to authorize its still not working

```
library(httr)
set_config(
use_proxy(url="10.3.100.207", port=8080)
)
```

i have even enabled internet2. but all the attempts are futile. any help ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running behind a proxy server, you'll want to configure the `shinyapps` package to use your proxy server. Checkout the docs in `?shinyapps::shinyappsProxies` for more information, but in short you'll likely want to do:

`Sys.setenv(http_proxy = "http://username:password@proxy.example.com:8080")`

It can be helpful to put this command in your `.Rprofile` so its runs everytime you launch R.